# Permance using varchar(750) or text

Tags: mysql, varchar

So, I'm building a table to input `images`.
I have an attribute to enter the caption/description of the image. In some cases, i need just a little more than `255` characters for the caption/description, around `500` and `750` characters... while in most cases 255 characters is just enough.

I'm not sure if I should use `varchar(750)` or `text` as the datatype for my caption/description attribute?

I've read the difference between both, but I could never find a clear answer on what is the best solution, performance wise.

Anyone with more knowledge on the issue?

Thanks